# Regex not matching when the start or end are empty

Tags: java, regex, string

Here is my regex as I have inputted it into my java file.

```
String myRegex = "(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9])(target)(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9])";
```

If I have a string as follows:

`.target.` - it works.

However, if I have a string that JUST says `target` it does not work. How can I modify the regex so that if there is nothing at the start or the end of the string, it still matches?

EDIT - Examples.

`_target` - Should succeed!

`target_` - Should succeed!

`target` - Should succeed!

Currently these examples fail with the current regex.

Comment: you need to create a regex which matches anything having `target`?

Comment: No it's more specific than that. I need a regex that does exactly what the existing regex does but also allows the start or end of the string to be empty.

Comment: `....the start or end of the string to be empty.....` can you show some example strings?

Comment: @NoobEditor Sorry, I added some examples

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, there are two negatives happening here. My lookbehinds are can be negative, and my character classes can be negatives. Currently, my lookbehinds are positive and my character classes are negatives. So it's saying: "Look behind and make sure you find something that is not within these classes". So when you there is nothing there, it won't find it and will fail. The solution was to make my look behind negative and make the character classes positive. So now it's saying "Look behind and sure there ISN'T any of these characters". So if it is empty, it won't fail because it meets the condition.

This is the final regex:

```
String myRegex = "(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])target(?![a-zA-Z0-9])";
```

Answer (score 2):

Add "start of input" to your look behind and add "end of input" to your look ahead using a regex *alternation* (ie `|` which is a logical "or"):

```
String myRegex = "(?<=^|[^a-zA-Z0-9])target(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]|$)";
```

The problem with your regex is that your look behind *required* there to be a preceding character that was not a letter/digit.

These look arounds also match start/end of input.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/xT6njQHFdF).

Comment: That makes perfect sense but I think my solution is cleaner.

Comment: @ogen actually, I agree :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, instead of using the look ahead and look behind, you can just use the `?` to indicate that there should be 0 or 1 non-alphabetical or numerical character before and after "target".

```
([^a-zA-Z0-9])?(target)([^a-zA-Z0-9])?
```

Comment: No because if I say `htarget` it will still match target. This is because the question mark means may or may not. So it just ignores it. With the lookbehind it won't match target because it starts with an h.

Comment: Oh, ok. So you want it to match anytime `target` appears not surrounded by letters or numbers?

Comment: Yeah I guess, I just want a simple way to add this little edge case to my current regex.

Comment: Ok. This might be considered kinda janky, but have you considered something like this? `(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9])(target)(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9])|^(target)$`

Comment: [Here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/o5wq43003eq0vnl/Regex_Testing.jar) is a simple regex tester made by [Ian Darwin](http://darwinsys.com), if it helps you.

Comment: @s.py That will work for `target` but not `target_` or `_target`. And to add those edge cases it will look a lot worse...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to match target using the * 0 or more quantifier to match any target which have 0 or more occurrences of the characters you want. So:

```
[_]*(target)[_]*
```

should match:

```
_target
target
target_
_target_
```

Add any element you want to be matched before or after the word to the brackets. Example to match `.target.` too:

```
[\._]*(target)[\._]*
```

This will match target substring no matter what part of the string it is. If you want to make the rule only for match at the start of the string then add the `^` anchor to it like:

```
^[\._]*(target)[\._]*
```

and will match the ones mentioned above only if they start the string.